# Will temp variable in always_comb create latch

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have following code snippet where a temp variable is used to count number of 1s in an array:

```
   // count the number 1s in array 
   logic [5:0] count_v; //temp
   always_comb begin
      count_v = arr[0];
      if (valid) begin
         for (int i=1; i<=31; i++) begin
            count_v = arr[i] + count_v;
         end
      end
      final_count = count_v;
   end
```

Will this logic create a latch for count_v ? Is synthesis tool smart enough to properly synthesize this logic? I am struggling to find any coding recommendation for these kind of scenarios.

Another example:

```
logic temp; // temp variable
always_comb begin
   temp = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<32; i++) begin
      if (i>=start) begin
         out_data[temp*8 +: 8] = in_data[i*8 +: 8];
         temp = temp + 1'b1;
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For any always block with deterministic initial assignment, it will not generate latch except logic loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Eddy Yau, we seem to have some discussions going on regarding your post.

Here is some example code:

```
module latch_or_not (
   input            cond,
   input      [3:0] v_in,
   output reg       latch,
   output reg [2:0] comb1,
   output reg [2:0] comb2

   );

reg [2:0] temp;
reg [2:0] comb_loop;

  // Make a latch
  always @( * )
     if (cond)
        latch = v_in[0];

  always @( * )
  begin : aw1
     integer i;
     for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1)
       comb_loop = comb_loop + v_in[i];
     comb2 = comb_loop;
  end

  always @( * )
  begin : aw2
     integer i;
     temp = 7;
     for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1)
       temp = temp - v_in[i];
     comb1 = temp;
  end

endmodule
```

This is what came out if it according to the Xilinx Vivado tool after elaboration:

The 'latch' output is obvious. You will also notice that temp is not present in the end result.

The 'comb_loop' is not a latch but even worse: it is a combinatorial loop. The output of the logic goes back to the input. A definitely NO-NO!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

General rule: if you read a variable before writing to it, then your code implies memory of some sort. In this case, both the simulator and synthesiser have to implement storage of a previous value, so a synthesiser will give you a register or latch. Both your examples write to the temporary before reading it, so no storage is implied.

Does it synthesisie? Try it and see. I've seen lots of this sort of thing in production code, and it works (with the synths I've used), but I don't do it myself. I would try it, see what logic is created, and use that to decide whether you need to think more about it. Counting set bits is easy without a loop, but the count loop will almost certainly work with your synth. The second example may be more problematical.

Comment: Not true, You will not get a latch as the variable always gets a value. You get a latch if there is one conditional path where no value is assigned.

Comment: You are right, EML: if you read a variable before writing to it, you will get a latch (unless the always block is clocked, then you get a flip-flop).

Comment: Sorry. @Oldfart. EML is right. Yes, you will get a latch if there is one conditional path where no value is assigned, but you will also get a latch if you read a variable before writing to it.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor: ah, I detect someone else who has taught VHDL :)

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I just tried reading a variable before assigning it in Vivado and I do NOT get a latch. I assume the construct you are referring to must be more complex then this: `nb = temp;  temp = par_tx[0];  for (i=1; i<DW; i=i+1)   temp = temp + par_tx[i]; ` temp disappears and nb is a combinatorial path.

Comment: @Oldfart: can't really say much without seeing all your code, but I would guess that since `nb` is unused, it's optimised out, so it's 'has-memory' behaviour is not relevant. The important thing is that the the synthesised netlist must have the behaviour that would be expected from pre-synthesis simulation by an LRM-compliant simulator. If it doesn't, then the synth got it wrong, or should simply have told you that it didn't understand what was required.

Comment: @Oldfart EML is right - I am confusing my Verilog and VHDL. We also need to consider blocking and non-blocking assignments too when considering clocked always Blocks. This will give you latches: `always @(*) begin : blk
  integer i;
  for (i=1; i<8; i=i+1) 
    temp = temp + par_tx[i];
end`, but you could argue that is because of the obvious feedback as much as the reading of `temp` before writing to it.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I also thought that would give a latch but it does not. See answer below where it generates a combinatorial loop. Wrong code either way.